# Webhook in Integromat

Tags: make.com

How can I store the results into a variable from a webhook response on integromat and display it on the sendpulse chatbot message?

[Scenario Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUQHh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the JSON using Parse JSON Module and then use the variables that you want to get.

To do that, Add Parse JSON Module, then add new data structure, use the JSON that you are receiving from the Webhooks through Generator method. Please refer the screenshot, after that you should be able to use the variable obtained from the Webhooks.
[image]

But, By default the Webhook should parse the JSON that is coming from the webhook unless you are not receiving JSON format from the webhook that you setup. So, The workaround for this will be to use ParseJSON module.